# How to achieve Expand collapse Side Nav with icon using jQuery and bootstrap css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have almost done my job for expand collapse side nav using jQuery and Bootstrap. here is my html and screen shot.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <%--Add the css reference here--%>
    <link href="../css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ToggleSideMenu").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
                    </span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Start Bootstrap </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="#ToggleSideMenu" class="btn btn-default" id="ToggleSideMenu">Toggle Menu</a>
            <hr />
            <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2015 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### screen shot

[image]

in my case nav is getting expand and collapse by button by i want to do with icon which will be sticky with nav bar. here i am giving a url which looks same as per my requirement.

```
http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=conquer
```

[image]

just tell me what to change in my html and css to get a little icon stick with my left side nav. if possible please help me with code sample. thanks

Comment: You could position the button inside the navbar in your html and position it absolutely in the top right in your css. If you intend to hide the sidebar completely when you click the button don't forget to set a negative value for the right attribute in your css, in order for the button to stay on screen. This would require you to keep the overflow in your sidebar visible.

Comment: would u plzz post some relevant code coz i am lost in html and css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move your button inside your navbar-header div, like this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
        </span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
</div>
```

Then, in your css:

```
.navbar-header {
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    position: absolute;  // this takes the button out of the regular document flow 
    left: 100%;    // this will stick the button on the outside right edge -- reduce this if you want the button more inside of the navbar-header
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);  // this & the rule above it will center the button vertically relative to the navbar-header
}
```

Comment: This is an example with the markup you already have.  https://jsfiddle.net/9dmLdtLq/2/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple sidebar with a toggle button inside of it.
When you click on it, it toggles a class `.sidebar-collapsed`, which will apply attributes to hide the bar. Also, the button moves to the right to stay visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/xpp5sgg8/2/

**CSS**

```
.sidebar, .toggle {
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar {
    background:lightgrey;
    width:200px;
    height:100vh;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.toggle {
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    top:5px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:black;
}

.sidebar-collapsed {
     transform:translateX(-100%);   
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
}

.sidebar-collapsed .toggle {
    right:-5px;
     transform:translateX(100%);   
    -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);   
}
```

Comment: good but u did not use bootstrap. it would be nice if some one work with my posted code and change as per the desired result.